# Refresh Simple Captcha

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, captcha

I am using [simple captcha](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/) in my JSP. Everything is OK. I want to provide a refresh button alongside of captcha to allow user to change the captcha. Captcha changes only on refreshing the complete page but I don't want to reload whole page for it.

I need your suggestions on how I can implement this like using AJAX or JQuery to reload only  the captcha, not whole page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function reloadCaptcha(){
        var d = new Date();
        $("#captcha_image").attr("src", "/captcha_generator.jsp?"+d.getTime());
    }
</script>
   ...
<img id="captcha_image" src="/captcha_generator.jsp" alt="captcha image" width="200" height="50"/>
<img src="reload.jpg" onclick="reloadCaptcha()" alt="reload"width="40" height="40"/>
```

Comment: reload image is not able to click.. can you suggest me plz ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember how SimpleCaptcha works, but usually, you should simply change the 'src' attribute of you captcha `<img>`. Something like this on the `onClick` of your refresh button:

```
var img = document.getElementById('captcha_id');// captcha_id is the id attribute of your caprtcha img
img.src = 'Some new captcha url';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function reloadCaptcha(){
        var d = new Date();
        $("#captcha_image").attr("src", "captcha.php?"+d.getTime());
    } </script>

<img id="captcha_image" src="captcha.php" alt="captcha image" width="90" height="33"/> <img src="images/refresh.png" alt="reload" width="22" height="22" border="0" onclick="reloadCaptcha()" />
```